# "Method xxx can not be reflected" error in webservice call

Tags: .net, winforms, soap, web-services, obfuscation

Before obfuscation, the call to the webservice works like a charm.

After obfuscation i get this error.

Method ***obfuscatedText*.GetStringFromWebService** can not be reflected. There was an error reflecting ".

What could i do? Why do i get this error after obfuscation?

Comment: I use clickonce deployment. The tool i use for obfuscation seems to obfuscate all the referenced assemblies, including the reference to the web service. And I am still searching for the exclusions option...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you actually need to obfuscate the web service code, consider splitting the service into two parts: one part would only be the service contract (or the WebMethods if you're still using ASMX).

All the real work should be split out into a separate assembly. You can obfuscate that separate assembly in order to hide details of your implementation. But leave the "service layer" assembly untouched.